# How to display the replies count of the each user comments with show/hide option in node view page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, comments

Now, I am having comments section like this in node view page.

```
  Comment 1
    comment 11
    comment 12
  Comment 2
  Comment 3
    comment 31
    comment 32
    comment 33
```

But, I would to show this with show/hide option for replied comments with replies count. like below

```
  Comment 1
    show/hide 2 replies
    ------------------
    | comment 11     |
    | comment 12     | 
    ------------------
  Comment 2
  Comment 3
    show/hide  3 replies
    ---------------
    |  comment 31 |
    |  comment 32 |
    |  comment 33 |
    ---------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem . The best way to solve this is to create a new **CUSTOM MODULE**.
 - Create a new folder in Your `sites/all/modules` folder `custom_module` name could be anything.

- In folder create two files `custom_module.info` and `custom_module.module` and  a folder `js` . In that folder create a *.js* file `custom_module.js` .
- So now you .js file will be located at `sites/all/modules/custom/js/custom_module.js` . Now Go to `custom_module` folder and in **custom_module.info** file add the lines of code..

  ```
  name = Custom_module
  description = Displays total count of replies to a comment and add display toggler to the replies of the comment.
  core = '7.x'
  version = '7.x-1.x'
  dependencies[] = comment
  ```
- Now in your  **custom_module.module** file

  ```
  <?php
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','custom_module') '/js/custom.js');
  function custom_module_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
    $query = db_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE pid = :cid', array(':cid' => $variables['id'])) ;
    $result = $query->fetchField();
    $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']['title'] = 'reply </a> <span>('.$result.')</span> <span id="show-hide">Show</span>';
  }
  ```
- So what the module did is fetched the total no of replies of a comment from the database and appended them to reply link.
- A Simple jQuery file will get you what you wanted. Edit your `js/custom_module.js` file **custom_module.js** file

  ```
  (jQuery)(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('div.indented').css('display', 'none');
    (jQuery)('div.comment .comment-text ul li.comment-reply span').click( function() {
      if(jQuery('show-hide').html()=='Show') {
        jQuery('show-hide').html()='Hide';    
        (jQuery)(this).parents("div.comment").next().slideToggle();
      }
      else {
        jQuery('show-hide').html()='Show';
        (jQuery)(this).parents("div.comment").next().slideToggle();
      }
    });
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- Click On Show in Comments and it will toggle . I have also added a screenshot..

**SHOW**
[image: Show].

**HIDE**
[image: Hide]

Comment: Could you elaborate **how** should he do it and what he's supposed to put inside that function?

Comment: Thanks Swastik Pareek. I am the beginner to drupal module. So, I did everything jquery.